# What happens at the end of a players turn to a buffed creature that took more than its unbuffed base health?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I have Blood Bairn and 3, 1/1 token creatures. An opponent attacks me with a 6/6 creature. If I use Blood Bairn's ability and sack all 3, 1/1 creatures and then block with Blood Bairn, after combat, the opponent creature should die and Blood Bairn survives. My question is this: at the end of his turn as Blood Bairn returns to a 2/2 creature, does it die because it took 6 damage from the previous combat?

Comment: Related Question: [When is “end of turn” in Magic?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5401/when-is-end-of-turn-in-magic)

Answer (score 10):

**Your [Blood Bairn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlood%20Bairn%5d) will survive.**

This is because "Until end of turn" buffs and Damage are removed at the same time during [the Cleanup-step](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Ending_phase#Cleanup_step).

> **514.2.** Second, the following actions happen simultaneously: all damage marked on permanents (including phased-out permanents) is removed and all “until end of turn” and “this turn” effects end. This turn-based action doesn’t use the stack.

Comment: Would this be a different outcome in a multiplayer match if my turn was not the next turn after the above combat?

Comment: @Legion413 Nope, Clean-up doesn't really care about who's turn it is now or next. All marked damage will be removed and all "until end of turn" effects will end, regardless of who owns/controls them.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help with my question. I love this community!

Comment: @Legion413 No problem, good first question. I recommend checking out the rules I linked for some more context and to better understand how cleanup works.

Comment: @Legion413 Also if you're satisfied with the answer, there's a check mark near the voting of the answer that allows you to accept it.  In case you didn't know.